# How do I target a single page to modify the comment form of only that page?

Tags: filters, hooks, comment-form

If I want to globally change the comment form for a theme I would use `add_filter` for "comment_form_default_fields". Then I might use `add_action` for "comment_form_logged_in_after" and "comment_form_after_fields". What I want to do, however, is create a single page with customised comment form fields.

My first thought was to add filters and use hooks in a custom page template. But that will, at best, work for one or two sites. What I am hoping to find is another way that I can target a chosen page. Is there a hook, filter, or logical test I can apply to modify a single page?

Comment: are you using the `body_class` and `post_class` functions? If so the classes they add can be used to do this for styling. I'm unsure how to add markup though

Comment: Thanks, Tom, if it were just a styling issue that would be a great approach. I'm looking to alter behaviour and add fields but only for one page.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go with a customizer setting, which a user could use to select a page (select) or pages (checkboxes) where the custom comment fields would be shown. The setting should save page ID(s).

Then I'd add a callback function to `template_redirect` action, which would first get the customizer setting value with `get_theme_mod()` and then compare the current query against the saved value. This could be either a `is_page()` check, if the user can only select one page, or a `is_array()` check with the `get_queried_object_id()` value, if the the user was allowed to choose multiple pages and the saved value was an array or turned into one.

If the above conditional check is passed, then appropriate action and filter callbacks would be applied to the comment form inside the `template_redirect` callback.

Or, if you want to use a custom page template instead of the customizer setting, then you could just swap the above conditional checks with `is_page_template()` and keep the concept otherwise the same.

But with customizer you could also provide options to the user to choose, which additional fields should be shown on the comment form, if needed. Each custom field should then have its own "is enabled" check and rendering callback in the `template_redirect` callback.

*P.s. I'm sorry for not adding code examples. I'm typing this on my mobile device and adding code this way is a bit inconvenient.*

Comment: No code needed, you said enough for me to fully understand.